# How to send a http post request to a rails app to get json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, typhoeus

For GET request its:-

```
 response = Typhoeus::Request.get("http://localhost:3000/users/1.json?oauth_token=12")
```

This returns Json response perfectly.

for Post request:-

```
   response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://localhost:3000/users/1.json?oauth_token=12",:params => {'[user][city]' => params[:location]})
```

is not working...

This is returning routing error.

Update:--

FOr login this api post call is working..

```
     response = Typhoeus::Request.post(API_SERVER_ADDRESS + "user_sessions.json" + API_OAUTH_TOKEN, :params => {'[user_session][email]' => params[:email], '[user_session][password]' =>params[:password]})
```

In routes its

```
resources :users
```

and also web http request is working perfectly fine..

**UPDATE**

For example http request from rails log is:--

```
   Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"8nvzCd0GF9IxjMcTfHOMJTPnycVPNIENMoMff8w4qAI=", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"1", "user"=>{ "city"=>"abc"}}
```

Now i want to sent same kind of request..

Comment: If you can explain the parms you're trying to pass a little more, I can update my example with appropriate code.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have punt, I'm stumped. To what API service are you posting that working login call? Is the other end something you've written? Just asking because the Typhoeus basics at the github site (https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) do not show anything like that :params setting you are using, with the bracketed string as the key... everything in the README is straight key-value pairs. If that works, then I'm just unfamiliar with that particular syntax.

Comment: @yardboy they how will you reformat this :params => {'[user_session][email]' => params[:email], '[user_session][password]' =>params[:password]}) or   "user"=>{ "city"=>"abc"}

Comment: Maybe something like: :params => { :user_session => { 'email' => params[:email], 'password' => params[:password] } }  This is what the params hash would look like in your controller, for instance, if all of this had come in from a form built in the standard manner, ie you'd access the email and password data as params[:user_session]['email'] and params[:user_session]['password'].

Comment: I already tried that..  But this doesnt work at all.

Comment: <punt> I'm stumped, then. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

From [this](http://rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/master/Typhoeus/Request/Actions#put-instance_method)

```
 response = Typhoeus::Request.put(API_SERVER_ADDRESS + "users/" +user_id + ".json" ,:params => {:oauth_token=>'12', :user=>{:city => params[:location]}})
```

Answer (score 1):

The :params parameter should be a hash of your parms, meaning key-value pairs, so maybe something like this:

```
response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://localhost:3000/users/1.json?oauth_token=12",:params => {:user => 'u', :city => 'c', :location => 'l'})
```

...or somesuch - whatever the parms are, whatever the values are. Your original doesn't translate into a meaningful hash for what you are wanting to do, I think.

Also, check your **routing** to make sure that what you are trying to do is properly routed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared a separate `POST` route in your `routes.rb` file. Even if the URLs are the same, different HTTP methods require different routes.

Using `resources :users` gives you the following by default:

```
GET     /users/new        # new
POST    /users            # create
GET     /users/:id        # show
GET     /users/:id/edit   # edit
PUT     /users/:id        # update
DELETE  /users/:id        # destroy
```

Comment: in routes its resources :users

Comment: Can you post the output from the server log?

Comment: It was  difficult to paste that log and then align in editor. So please check this screenshot. Meanwhile I am trying to update the question. http://cl.ly/4030152U001E0U113a1l

Comment: That looks more like the server response object. Are you running `rails server` in a terminal? That's the output I'm looking for.

Comment: @luke Yupp.. Basically i have developed web app in ruby on rails with inbuilt json api response calls. Now i am working on mobile site.. Thats where i am stuck.

Comment: Look in the terminal where you started `rails s`. There will be output everytime you hit the server. It'll look something like [this](http://www.pastie.org/2112768) but with errors, obviously.

Comment: I think problem is rounting.. Updating user should be put request and we are sending post request. Thats y its causing issue.. What say?